# C++ How do I solve very large system of sparse linear system

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, eigen, large-data

I am trying to solve a very large and sparse system of linear equations in C++. Currently, I am using BiCGSTAB from eigen. It works fine for small matrix, but it is taking just too much time for matrix of the size I need, which is 40804x40804 (It could be even larger in the future).

I have a very long script, but I simply used the following format:

```
SparseMatrix<double> sj(40804,40804);
VectorXd c_(40804), sf(40804);
sj.reserve(VectorXi::Constant(40804,36)); //This is a very good estimate of how many non zeros in each column
//...Fill in actual number in sj
sj.makeCompressed();
BiCGSTAB<SparseMatrix<double> > handler;
//...Fill in sj, only in the entries that have been initialized previously
handler.analyzePattern(sj)
handler.factorize(sj);
c_.setZero();
c_=handler.solve(sf);
```

This takes way too long! And yes, the solution does exist. Sparse function in matlab seems to handle this very well, but I need it in C++ in order to connect to a server.

I would really appreciate it you could help me!

Comment: If matlab do good job for you why not to use it in c++. [Link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/calling-matlab-software-from-a-c-application.html)

Comment: If connecting to a server is crucial maybe you should try pari/gp instead...

Comment: Make sure to compile with compiler optimizations ON, then you could also give a try to a direct solver like `Eigen::SparseLU` (just replace `BiCGSTAB` by `SparseLU`) or by using the `IncompleteLUT` preconditioner in BICGSTAB.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider use of one of the advanced sparse direct solvers: [CHOLMOD](https://developer.nvidia.com/cholmod)

Sparse direct solvers are a fundamental tool in computational analysis, providing a very general method for obtaining high-quality results to almost any problem. `CHOLMOD` is a high performance library for sparse [*Cholesky factorization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).

I guarantee that this package definetly will help you. Moreover `CHOLMOD` has supported *GPU acceleration* since 2012 with version 4.0.0 . In SuiteSparse-4.3.1 performance has been further improved, providing speedups of 3x or greater vs. the CPU for the sparse factorization operation.

If your matrices are the representations of graphs you can also consider [METIS](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview) with combination of `CHOLMOD`. Which means you will be able to do partition/domainDecomposition in graphs then parallel solve with `CHOLMOD`.

`SuiteSparse` is a powerfull tool with the support of linear(KLU) and direct solvers.

Here are the [GitHub link](https://github.com/PetterS/SuiteSparse/tree/master/CHOLMOD), [UserGuide](http://users.encs.concordia.ca/~krzyzak/R%20Code-Communications%20in%20Statistics%20and%20Simulation%202014/Zubeh%F6r/SuiteSparse/CHOLMOD/Doc/UserGuide.pdf) and [SuiteSparse's home page](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html)